# gallery image flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, image, gallery, image-gallery

The images aren't showing instead a loading spinner is shown.
Also, there's no onTap function or anything and when I tap an image (that's currently only a loading spinner) I get a black page with my appbar and another loading spinner.
When I get out of this page, I get an error saying (looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe)
Does anybody know how I can fix this or maybe another way of implementing the same look?

I am using the plugin exactly how it's used in pub.dev with my urls in a list passed on to GalleryImage's imageUrls

```
List<String> urls = [
'https://3.imimg.com/data3/AQ/LU/MY-9021275/plumber-work-contractor-dwarka-delhi-500x500.jpg',
'https://adoptostaging.blob.core.windows.net/media/plumber-job-description-template-tQh1-P.jpg',
'https://previews.123rf.com/images/nenovbrothers/nenovbrothers1811/nenovbrothers181100014/111300956-plumber-working-on-kitchen-sink.jpg',
'https://jobdescriptionandresumeexamples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Plumber.jpg',
'https://previews.123rf.com/images/bvb1981/bvb19811508/bvb1981150800055/43563732-.jpg'
```

];

```
SizedBox(
    child: GalleryImage(
    imageUrls: urls,
    titleGallery: 'المعرض',
        ),
       ),
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did. Do you have an idea what might be wrong?